# C# WPF Modern UI disable or hide LinkGroup

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

Hi Im writing a WPF application that has user login. I use Modern UI for this application. The application has following LinkGroups:

```
<mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
    <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="Group 1">
        <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
            <mui:Link DisplayName="A" Source="/Pages/A.xaml" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="B" Source="/Pages/B.xaml" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="C" Source="/Pages/C.xaml" />
        </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
    </mui:LinkGroup>
    <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="Group 2">
        <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
            <mui:Link DisplayName="D" Source="/Pages/D.xaml" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="F" Source="/Pages/F.xaml" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="G" Source="/Pages/G.xaml" />
        </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
    </mui:LinkGroup>
</mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
```

I want to hide or disable Link group named "Group 2" depending on user ID. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it is too late, but I think that had a solution.
Since `LinkGroup` is not derived from `UIElement` it is not possible to hide it, but you can work around this. I'm sure that it isn't the clearest solution, but it worked for me.

You can reach your `LinkGroup`s via

```
var window = App.Current.MainWindow as ModernWindow;
var toRemove = window.MenuLinkGroups.ElementAt(1);
```

`MenuLinkGroups` is a `Collection<T>` thus you can `Add` and `Remove` items.

```
window.MenuLinkGroups.Remove(toRemove);
```

Comment: argument out of bounds exception

Answer (score 2):

You can also generate a `LinkGroupCollection` after login and bind `ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups` to this collection.